# Definition of Simple Connectedness.

Tags: general-topology

I came accross the following defintion of simple-connectedness:

---

**Given:**

$S^1 =\{ (x,y)  \in R^2 \ | \ x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$

$K^2 =\{ (x,y)  \in R^2 \ | \ x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}$

With $\underline S^1, \underline K^2$ being subspaces of $\underline R^2$.

---

**Definitions:**

A *loop* in $\underline X$ is a continuous map  $f: \underline S^1 \rightarrow \underline X $.

A loop is *contractable* if there exists a continuous extension $F: \underline K^2 \rightarrow \underline X$ of $f$.

$\underline X$ is called *simply-connected* if $\underline X$ is path-connected and every loop in it is contractible.

---

I understand the definition of the *loop* as it describes a continuous path from point $x$ to itself, which is  a loop in its literal meaning.

What I don't get is the definition of *contractibility*. I don't see how extending $f$ as described above somehow leads to the ability of going around holes in $X$ to make the space simply-connected.

It is also a definition, which is similar to how simple-connectedness is described in Wikipedia. Describing its meaning might benefit others as well.

Comment: The idea is that if you can fill the circle you drew in $X$ with a disk, then you can shrink it  to a point inside this disk. You cannot fill the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ with a disk, and visually, it is clear that you cannot shrink the unit circle to a point in thus configuration.

Comment: The circle and the disk are not in $\underline X$, they are subspaces of $\underline R^2$.

Comment: Well, I know that. It is just that a continuous function from the circle to $X$ can be thought as "drawing a circle (= a loop) in $X$". Same thing with a continuous function from the disk to $X$: it is "colouring a disk in $X$". This is what the definition of simple-connectedness is suggesting: every circle drawn on a simply connected topological space $X$ bounds a disk in $X$ and can be shrinked into a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $t\in[0,1]$ and each $z\in S^1$, let $f_t(x)=F(tz)$. Then $f_1=f$ and $f_0$ is constant. And, due to continuity, $f_t$ is close to $f_1$ if $t$ is close to $1$ and $f_t$ is close to $F(0)$ if $t$ is close to $0$. So, the $f_t$'s deform the loop $f_1(=f)$ into a single point.

Comment: Is this similar to what a Homotopy is?

Comment: Yes, it is similar.

Comment: I'm a relative novice in topology, so I have hard time grasping things quickly. From what I read now about homotopy and what you've written I conclude that you define some sort of family of *paths* and then say that these paths range continuously from the initial one $f$ if t = 1 and a fully contracted one $F(0)$ if $t =0$. If $t$ transitions from $1$ to $0$ then this family of paths also smoothly transitions from initial path $f$ to a constant function F(0), latter signifying a path from some $p$ to $p$ itself, a single point path.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.